# how to sort multiple added column

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

i have tables which are relationships between them `Tours` and `Comments`. In view i have filter 1) new 2) popular 3) old.

I want to select popular by sum of columns(let's assume `col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d`) in `Comments` which are users were left rate for this `Tour`
here is my code:

`$tours = $tours->comment()->select(DB::raw('housing, destination, nutrition, transport, price AS total_points'))->orderBy('total_points', 'desc');`

$tours should be as a object because at the end i seen this result with paginate. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **Sum** to add columns

```
$tours = $tours->comment()->select(DB::raw(SUM('housing, destination, nutrition, 
transport, price) AS total_points'))->orderBy('total_points', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```